# OpenSSL connection Error called stream_socket_enable_crypto()

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, stream

in  my php coding i have following line which uses by SWIFT MAILER Class

```
if(!stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->smtp_conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)) {

  return false;

}
```

however rarely (not always) i get following php error

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

i am not sure where the problem is or should i ignore this as this happens only once in a while

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.3.6-8ubuntu0ppa5~lucid1 with the PHPMailer class and I see the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

It was caused by incorrect SMTP settings. I had:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.myserver.com', 465, 'tls');
```

and as soon as I corrected it to

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.myserver.com', 465, 'ssl');
```

it worked normally. Quite a non-intuitive error message but I got there in the end.

Comment: i change SMTPSecure tls to ssl, and Port 586 to 465, and working now.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini search for line

```
; extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and remove ; so it becomes:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Then save & restart & enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` is code for the server not using SSL/TLS at all.

So, make sure to check that first.